# Laravel Doesn’t Take a Parameter in a Function

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, fetch-api

I'm making a simple chat application with an API and Ajax; the problem is when I make the Ajax request and store in my datebase a chat conversation and the message if the conversation exists just save the message.
But when I save the message, the request does not take an ID, but when I save a chat take it.

**Laravel**

```php
public function storeMsj(Request $req)
{
    $existChat = $this->existsChat($req->id);
    if ($existChat == 0) {
        Chat::create([
            'user' => $req->id,//here take the request
            'read' => 0,
        ]);

        Message::create([
            'message_content' => $req->msj,
            'from' => $req->id,//here not take the request
            'to' => 1,
        ]);
    } else {
        Message::create([
            'message_content' => $req->msj,
            'from' => $req->id,
            'to' => 1,
        ]);
    }

    return Response::json($req->id);//the response show correctly the request
}
```

**JS**

```
function storeMsj(){
    let msj = document.querySelector('.msg').value;
    let id = idUser.firstElementChild.innerHTML;

    fetch('/api/storeMsj',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-type': 'aplication/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            msj: msj,
            id: id
        }),
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    .then(response => console.log('Success:', response)); 
}
```

Comment: Are the `user` and `from` fields fillable? Please provide any values you have set for the `$fillable` or `$guarded` properties in your `Chat` and `Message` models.

Comment: No, that was the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel Mass Assignment, you will need to specify a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

```
    class Flight extends Model
    {
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
   }
```